# Using odds ratios in robumeta package (R)

Tags: r

I am using the 'robu' function of the 'robumeta' package to perform a meta-analysis and account for non-independent effect sizes. I am using odds ratios as my metric, which prior to analysis I transformed to log odds ratios. Is it possible to back transform the log odds ratios to conduct a forest plot using the 'forest.robu' function? Is there a function for that (similar to 'transf=exp' in 'predict' function in 'metafor' package)?

Many thanks,

Anna

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like *robu* supports that (it's not a particularly feature-complete package). But, you can fit cluster-robust models with *metafor*.

```r
library(metafor)
#> Loading required package: Matrix
#> Loading required package: metadat
#> 
#> Loading the 'metafor' package (version 3.1-49). For an
#> introduction to the package please type: help(metafor)

### fit random-effects model
res <- rma(yi = yi ~ 1, vi = vi, test = "knha", data = dat.bangertdrowns2004)

### obtain results based on the sandwich method
res_robust <- robust(res, cluster = id, clubSandwich = TRUE)

forest(res_robust, transf = transf.exp.int, 
       targs = list(tau2 = res_robust$tau2, lower = -4, upper = 4))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-03-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

(Note that the `transf.exp.int()` transformation is a bias-corrected variation on `exp()` that accounts for the nonlinearity in the `exp()` transformation. The `exp()` transformation yields the estimated *median* odds ratio, rather than the *mean* odds ratio.